# Как передать из формы html в php значение даты

Tags: php

Хочу передать дату и время из

```html
 <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="dateC" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); ?>" id="example-datetime-local-input">
```

В переменную `$date` в таком же формате `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` как это осуществить?

Comment: она попадёт в $_REQUEST('dateC')

Comment: А как мне тогда передать его в переменную? Есть такая возможность?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="dateC" value="<?=date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); ?>" id="example-datetime-local-input">
<button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Файл form.php

```
<?
    $date = $_POST['dateC'];
?>
```